# Decaptcher C# API?

Tags: c#

I've downloaded the API from their site but it's a .NET 1.0, I converted it to 3.0 and it wont work.

All I need is some documentation on using the .dll.

Not sure how many people have used it but hoping someone can shed a little light onto the subject.

Comment: You're probably not going to get any assistance on SO.. probably need to pose the question to them

Comment: Why's that? There is a legitimate reason for using decaptcher services.

Is it possible to view the contents of the DLL? Or view 1.0 data?

Comment: Because you're asking a very niche question that is best served by the developers of decaptcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use their POST API?

```
http://poster.decaptcher.com/
```

Forget about fiddling with their c# API; been there, tried that, and it's easier to just POST the data to the above url.

Check [their site](http://api.decaptcher.com/client/) for more info (click "Download", scroll to the POST API).

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on using any DLL: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Sometimes that is all the documentation you get.

Comment: Ha, I got reflector. Was not aware it could be used with DLL's.

Comment: Ah, its not a .NET DLL so it dont work.

Comment: You said it was a .NET 1.0 DLL which you "converted to 3.0"  Where in the process did it become something other than .NET?